# Dell studio XPS 1645 on Ubuntu 16.04 wifi not working

Tags: networking, wireless, dell

I moved my hard drive from a *Dell Vostro 1700* to a *Dell studio XPS 1645* with Ubuntu 16.04.
But the WiFi is not working. The ethernet works for a few seconds and then disconnects. I tried

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

and the result was

```
*-network DISABLED
description: Wireless interface
product: Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300
vendor: Intel Corporation
```